# Why canvas drawImage doesn't work if using the dom image element?

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas

I wrote a canvas js program, but it doesn't work if I use the DOM element in ubuntu 13.04 chromium(it is fine in firefox 23.0). Here is the code:

```
<body>
<canvas id="map" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
<img id="photo" src="jiuwo.jpg" style="display:none;">
<img id="frame" src="frame.png" style="display:none;">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function drawGallary(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('map');
    if(canvas.getContext){
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var img1 = document.getElementById('photo');
        var img2 = document.getElementById('frame');
        ctx.drawImage(img1, 300, 300, 100, 100, 20, 21, 100, 100); // block of image
        ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
    }
}
</script>
```

I found that if I put the drawImage into onload function ,it works well:

```
function drawGallary2(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('map');
    if(canvas.getContext){
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var img1 = new Image();
        img1.src = "jiuwo.jpg";
        img1.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(img1, 300, 300, 100, 100, 20, 21, 100, 100);
        }
        var img2 = document.getElementById('frame');
        img2.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

is that onload needed if using the DOM element to be the image source? Thanks.

Comment: It is needed to make sure image is loaded before you draw it.

Comment: How is `drawGallery()` called?

Comment: Something you did wrong. Check this example http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_drawimage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you give time for the page to fully load using window.onload.

That way your images are fully available to draw on the canvas.

```
// wait until the page is fully loaded

window.onload = function() {

    function drawGallary(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('map');
        if(canvas.getContext){
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var img1 = document.getElementById('photo');
            var img2 = document.getElementById('frame');
            ctx.drawImage(img1, 300, 300, 100, 100, 20, 21, 100, 100); 
            ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
        }
    }

} // end window.onload
```

Comment: it works well when I call drawGallary in after window.onload, in old version I alert the element and it show it's an image element, but actually the element didn't load. thanks.